# firestore updateDoc replaces entire field instead of updating?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to figure what I am doing incorrectly here when I want to update just a value of my field in the firestore but instead the entire field got replaced?

also for whatever reason my `date` variable seems to directly become the string `date` in firestore instead of the value it holds?

Here's my code for updating the Doc:

```
export async function addLikesToFeed(date, likes){
    try{
        // it literally updates to {'date': 'likes: 1'}
        await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Bulletin', `bulletin`), { date: {likes: likes+1}})
    } catch(error){
        console.log('error updating Likes at addLikesToFeed: ', error.message)
    }
}
```

The below is a screen shot of my firestore. If I hard code `'05-02-2022'` in the `date` part, it becomes like what you see in the image. If I kept `date` as seen in the code, it becomes the `date like` part.

the `date` variable holds a string and `likes` is a number.

I want my function to work so that when I click on my button it will add one like to the value in the `likes` part, and I am trying to figure out why I cant do that

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the value of `date` as the field name, you can use `[]` notation:

```
await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Bulletin', `bulletin`), { [date]: {likes: likes+1}})
```

This will still replace the entire field for that date though. If you want to update only the `likes` subfield, you can use [dot notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to update fields in nested objects:

```
await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Bulletin', `bulletin`), { [date+".likes"]: likes+1})
```

Finally, Firestore actually has a build in operator for [incrementing values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), which prevents race conditions when multiple users are updated the `likes` values at almost the same time.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for your update and thorough explanation. My console is throwing me unexpected token at the ```+".likes"``` part though

Comment: Ah yeah, I see I had a typo. Check the edit, where I moved the `]` to the end of the field name expression.

Comment: if you dont mind me asking, can the dot notation be used to go as deep as need? i.e. something like ```[date+ ' .likes ' + ' .users ' + ' .apples ' + ' .oranges ' ...``` ?

Comment: Dot notation can go multiple levels.  Give it a try, and let me know if you run into issues!

Comment: Hi Frank hope you are doing well. Just a quick question is there a similar function like ```increment``` for objects? currently I have ```await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Posts', `posts`), { [date+".comments"] : {...originalComments, [name] : comment}``` but I can imagine there will be issues when one two users loaded at the same time but update at different times hence it might overwrite the other

Comment: or would something like this works as intended : ```await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Posts', `posts`), { [date+".comments"+`.${[name]}`] :comment```

Comment: That sounds like a new question @SushiRiceOverEggs, so that others can also weigh in. ;-)